# Clearing buffer while reading in binary data from a server in C++

Tags: c++, server, binary-data, datareader

I have a server that sends raw binary data to print a "map" that a user must traverse through, however, I am having trouble clearing out my buffer after each line read and thus keep getting residual data printed at the end of the shorter lines. In the screenshot below you can see my output on the left, and what the output *should* be on the right. What is the best way to solve this? I feel like I am missing something but cant seem to find a solution.

[image]

And the code that is reading/printing this is below:

```
char* mapData = NULL;
string command = "command> ";
size_t dataSize = 0;
while(mapData != command.c_str()) {
    unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*) &dataSize;
    connection = read(mySocket, buffer, 8);
    if(connection == -1 || connection < 0) {
        cerr << "**Error: could not read text size" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    mapData = (char*)malloc(dataSize);
    buffer = (unsigned char*) mapData;

    while((connection = read(mySocket, buffer, dataSize)) != -1) {
        if(connection == -1 || connection < 0) {
            cerr << "**Error: could not read text size" << endl;
        return 1;
        }
        if(dataSize != 1) {
            cout << buffer;
        }
        free(buffer);
        buffer = NULL;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the inner while loop iterates more than once? If so, freeing buffer inside that loop is almost definitely incorrect.

Comment: On a couple of unrelated notes: You don't need the `buffer` variable. Pass `&dataSize` directly to the `read` call. Also pass `sizeof dataSize` instead of hard-coding `8`. And don't forget that `read` will return `0` if the socket is close, something you need to handle as well. Lastly, if you use TCP sockets, then a single `read` call may return *less* than what was written, you need to call `read` in a loop until all requested data has been received.

Comment: Use the return value from `read` which is the number of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of `read()` to know how many bytes are in the buffer.

`read()` returns the actual number of bytes that were read, which may be fewer than you requested. So you need to call `read()` in a loop until you have read all of the bytes you are expecting, eg:

```
int readAll(int sock, void *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    unsigned char* pbuf = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buffer);
    while (buflen > 0) {
        int numRead = read(sock, pbuf, buflen);
        if (numRead < 0) return -1;
        if (numRead == 0) return 0;
        pbuf += numRead;
        buflen -= numRead;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Also, after reading the buffer, you are treating it as if it were null-terminated, but it is not, which is why you get extra garbage in your output.

More importantly, `mapData != command.c_str()` will ALWAYS be true, so your `while` loop iterates indefinitely (until a socket error occurs), which is not what you want. You want the loop to end when you receive a `"command> "` string instead.

`mapData` is initially NULL, and `c_str()` NEVER returns NULL, so the loop ALWAYS iterates at least once.

Then you allocate and free `mapData` but don't reset it to NULL, so it is left pointing at invalid memory. Which doesn't really matter, since your `while` loop is just comparing pointers.  `c_str()` will NEVER return a pointer to memory that `mapData` ever points to.

To end your loop correctly, you need to compare the *contents* of `mapData` after reading, not compare its *memory address*.

Try this instead:

```
char *mapData = NULL;
uint64_t dataSize = 0;
const string command = "command> ";
bool keepLooping = true;

do {
    if (readAll(mySocket, &dataSize, sizeof(dataSize)) <= 0) {
        cerr << "**Error: could not read text size" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (dataSize == 0)
        continue;

    mapData = new char[dataSize];

    if (readAll(mySocket, mapData, dataSize) <= 0) {
        cerr << "**Error: could not read text" << endl;
        delete[] mapData;
        return 1;
    }

    cout.write(mapData, dataSize);

    keepLooping = (dataSize != command.size()) || (strncmp(mapData, command.c_str(), command.size()) != 0);

    delete[] mapData;
}
while (keepLooping);
```

Alternatively:

```
string mapData;
uint64_t dataSize = 0;
const string command = "command> ";

do {
    if (readAll(mySocket, &dataSize, sizeof(dataSize)) <= 0) {
        cerr << "**Error: could not read text size" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    mapData.resize(dataSize);

    if (dataSize > 0) {
        if (readAll(mySocket, &mapData[0], dataSize) <= 0) {
            cerr << "**Error: could not read text" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        cout << mapData;
    }
}
while (mapData != command);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Only issue is its not printing out the "command> " itself but a little messing around should fix that. Thank you!

Comment: @ejscribner it should be printing out everything that is received. However, `cout` is usually buffered, so you may need to flush it once the command has been received, via `cout << flush` or `cout.flush()`

Answer (score 1):

like @eozd pointed out, calling `malloc` and `free` in your loop is a bad idea since you use `return` statements. Your code may leak memory. You should ensure you call `free` before returns. Even better, you could declare your `buffer` outside of `while loop`, and use `break` instead of `return`, and call `free` if there was en error

Looking at your solution, it seems that the communication protocol involves sending data size first, followed by the actual data. How is data size written to the wire? You may need to convert it from network byte order.

To debug, you could print out the value of `dataSize` before every read to make sure that it is what you expect

Comment: Before each line of actual data, it sends a size_t that represents how many bytes need to be read, however when I print the dataSize it prints the proper size (18 for line 1, then 10 for the rest of the lines) but still leaves the 'Miffy!' at the end of each of the remaining shorter lines.

Comment: what happens if you put `memset(buffer, 0, datasize);` right before `free(buffer)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the buffer too. Add:

```
 memset(mapData, 0, dataSize);
```

after the `malloc`.